# How to display trigger error as a message box or Aler Box on Approval Process Page

Tags: community, community-builder, developer-productivity

Since days I am trying on this thing and no winning. I have written a trigger and controller to display error when approval or rejection is provided without providing comments. This error displays on another page, which does not appear good from users UI perspective.

Is there a way to produce this error on the same approval page just similar to validation errors on top of the page or with the field. Or it can be presented as an alert message on the same approval page.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce out of box functionality provides approval related error message in separate page. Basically this is a generic URL Salesforce has built to show approval related functionalities.

Salesforce doesn't provide an option to show error message in the same record detail page

Comment: Isn't there any way, this can be achieved. I learnt in salesforce, that even if any solution is not made available by salesforce, but our creative IT brains find way around to achieve their objectives as per the requirements. I am sure there would also be some hacky way around it. I am trying since couple of days, but not getting a crack of this. Please suggest.

Comment: Then wait for some other expert to chime in.